# Firebase analytics in Android - Multiple events sending in for-loop showing multiple event's property value instead of single property value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I have to send list of data in firebase events but as firebase not supporting to send ArrayList data in firebase event property. So, i am sending multiple events using for loop. Events are calling multiple times but its value contains multiple entry. 
for example i have 4 items to send in firebase, and events are calling 4 times as expected, but its event property contains 4 values which is wrong. I want to send multiple events in for loop with single value.

[image]

I tried multiple ways but its showing above result. My code snippet is here,

```
val bundle = Bundle()
for (reorder in reorderList) {
     bundle.putString(PROP_DRUG_NAME, reorder.drug)
     bundle.putString(PROP_MISSED_DUE_DATE,if (reorder.missedDrug) PROP_VALUE_YES else PROP_VALUE_NO)      
     FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)?.logEvent(EVENT_DRUGS_REORDER, bundle)
     bundle.clear()
    }
```

Also Android studio console showing items one time

```
Logging event (FE): drugs_reorder, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=app, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=xxxActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=xxx, drug_name= xxxx, missed_due_date=yes}]
```

Comment: Hello!I think, your should init val bundle = Bundle() into loop. Also,  RxJava (RxKotlin) support a zip request, when several requests zipping to one request. May be your should  user Rx?

Comment: I tried with putting val bundle=Bundle() into for loop but it was not working. And here i want to send multiple request but data showing multiple times in firebase dashboard.

Comment: Same happens with me in iOS swift, multiple parameter values in for loop.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?